# Unable to get message from queue in IBM websphere MQ

Tags: asp.net, get, remoting, ibm-mq

I am connecting remotely to MQ on the server and i installed MQ client v6.0 on my machine.
I am able to put the message into the queue but i am unable to get the message from the same queue the output is "RC2033: MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE"

Can anyone please help me to find the issue?

Will this be due to properties of the queue?

The following is the code which i am using to pop the message :

**Pop Message:**

```
queue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue("queue_name", MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED);
MQMessage queueMessage = new MQMessage();
queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
MQGetMessageOptions queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
queueGetMessageOptions.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT;
queueGetMessageOptions.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;
queueGetMessageOptions.WaitInterval = 1000;
queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);
tbPoptxt.Text = "Message No" + count + ":" + queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
```

**PUSH CODE**

```
int optons = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;//Queue which opens with options output
        queue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue("queue_name", optons);
        MQMessage queueMessage = new MQMessage();
        queueMessage.WriteString(tbPushtxt.Text.ToString());
        queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
        MQPutMessageOptions queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
        queuePutMessageOptions.Options = MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
        queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
```

mqQMgr.Commit();

I am using same queue for putting a message and poping a message

Comment: Are you sure the incoming messages have the format MQC.MQFMT_STRING? Comment out queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING; and test.

Comment: @Shashi I commented the line but no difference in output

Comment: I tried from cmd also by using a command "amqsputc queue_name queue_manager" i received same error message as "MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE"

Comment: I am using MQv7.5 client and your snippet works perfectly fine. BTW MQ v6 is out of support. Try with MQ v7.1 or MQ v7.5 client.

Comment: Why are you suspecting the program for this error. Are you sure message is still there in the queue and then also you are getting the above error.

Comment: your are correct there is no message in the queue and there is a  problem in putting a queue.Kindly see the first comment of below answer and plz reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the samples directory for the nmqsput and nmqsget c# examples - these do exactly what you are after and are good working examples.

Looking at the code above, I do not think there is a problem getting the message, followed up by your comment that amqsputc failed to find a message as well. I think the problem is on the putting side.

This may sound a silly question, but how do you know the message is there. What is the curdepth after the put? Look at the queue status - are there any uncommitted messages? (One thing I've seen before is putting under a unit of work (syncpoint) and then not committing and then another application trying to get it.

Comment: I think your silly question is my error ........I have problem in putting a message to MQ.When I first load the page the queue depth is 0 and than i try to put a message twice without disconnecting a queue or queue manager.Than it shows depth of the queue has 2.But if i disconnect the MQM or closes the queue than queue depth is shown as 0 again.......Is this  because of not committing? .........I tried to commit using queuemanager.commit().....IS there any other way to do that?

Comment: I tried with command prompt with command "amqsputc queue_name queue_manager" and put a message and than used command to check the message in queue using "amqsbcg queue_name queue_manager" it is showing me as "NO More message".

Comment: I have added MQPUT code to  question as "PUSH CODE"  ...@nitgeek

Comment: The Push code is flawed. You are using the *get* options (MQGMO_) on a *put* (so MQPMO_). However even after that note the use of MQPMO_SYNCPOINT - this says to the queue manager put it to the queue and dont make it available just yet (it will be held in a unit of work). Either remove the use of syncpoint, or (much better) ensure you commit (mqQMgr.Commit();)

Comment: I changed the options from MQGMO to MQPMO_SYNCPOINT and committed with with command mqQMgr.Commit()....still not working

Comment: Look closely and test with the sample nmqsput/nmqsget samples - they do almost exactly the code above. After the put, check the CURDEPTH of the queue, and the queue status for UNCOMmitted messages. You should have a depth of 1, and UNCOM(NO) (runmqsc qmgrname, DIS QSTATUS(queuename) all, DIS QL(queuename) CURDEPTH. Test with amqsput/amqsget (local bindings), then amqsputc and amqsgetc (client bindings) until you can put/get a message, then replace one of the two with your .net code and see if it works.